Modificar tamaño de imagenes de un carrusel usando la libreria flowbite
Lo que ocupo que las imágenes que coloque en el carrusel tengan una relación de mas altura que ancho. El tamaño de las imágenes son de 1080x2460 (tienen mas alto que ancho), pero flowbite en su componente de carrusel solo me permite las imágenes como en el ejemplo:

Probe con algunas clases de su documentación, pero no me funciono.
Y ocupo que las imágenes mantengan la relación de llevar mas alto x ancho. Que sea como el siguiente ejemplo (Disculpen la calidad de la imagen). Gracias de antemano! :

El código del carrusel el cual intento usar se encuentra en la pagina de => flowbite <=

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
